# how to enable drivers for BCM43142

Tags: wireless, broadcom

My laptop is Dell Inspiron 17R 5720. My OS is Ubuntu 13.10. I was using WiFi before but one day it stopped working.
Outputs of some commands:

```
enedil@enedil-Dell:~$ lspci -k | grep -A2 Broadcom
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0
Kernel driver in use: wl


enedil@enedil-Dell:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no


enedil@enedil-Dell:~$ lsmod | grep wl
wl                   4207760  0 
cfg80211              480503  1 wl
lib80211               14381  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip


enedil@enedil-Dell:~$ uname -a
Linux enedil-Dell 3.11.0-15-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 9 18:17:04 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


enedil@enedil-Dell:~$ lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n     [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

I don't know what to do, especially that yesterday, I changed my Internet connection to wireless.

EDIT: When I click on network applet (I'm using Unity) I see message under grey Wi-Fi: Device unsupported.

Comment: Please check the message logs for any informative clues: dmesg | grep -e wl -e eth1

Comment: There isin't any output.

Comment: Please try: sudo modprobe wl and then: dmesg | grep -e wl -e eth1

Comment: FATAL: Module wl not found.

Comment: Try sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

Answer (score 2):

Please reinstall the driver. With a temporary wired ethernet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Detach the ethernet. Your wireless should be working now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have previously installed the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package, you will need to remove it by using the purge method:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Prepare the installation:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Update the Ubuntu list of PCI IDs:

```
sudo update-pciids
```

Install the driver:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Finally, reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```