# Ubuntu 14.04 in lenovo g700 can't detect any wireless networks?

Tags: wireless, networking, lenovo

I have a new Lenovo g700 notebook, and just installed Ubuntu 14.04 , but it seems not to be able to configure or list the wireless networks, How can i solve this problem :\

Any advice will greatly appreciated, regards

trying lspci -nn| grep 0280

gives back:

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]:broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365](rev 01)

Comment: Without verifying, how can you be certain he has a Broadcom?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: The question is edited!

Comment: First type this command: $ ls /sys/class/net This will list all the interface names for all NICs on your computer. The wifi NIC will look something like wlan0 or wifi0. Then type in the command: $ sudo iwlist [wifi interface] scan to scan for available wifi networks. Here, [wifi interface] is the NIC for wlan0 you got from the above command. If you get any error please post here thank you!

Comment: The correct driver will be installed by the Additional Drivers tool.

Comment: i followed this and helped me
http://askubuntu.com/questions/402341/how-to-enable-drivers-for-bcm43142

Answer (score 0):

I just had a same problem and I found that you may need to install broadcom linux wireless driver.

From the shell:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source

Then the wireless connections would be working.

You can check out broadcom's website for more information http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt