# WIFI Drivers Semi Solved

Tags: additional-drivers

Ok so I own a Lenovo Ideapad G70-80 and I've been trying to Ubuntu on it but the WiFi Drivers aren't detected. I've tried Kubuntu, Ubuntu, Mint, OpenSuse, Fedora, among a few. Today I took UbuntuStudio 16.04 and to my surprise the WiFi Drivers work on it. So my question is then what is the process I need to take those drivers and use them in a linux flavor I prefer?

Comment: Ho do we know what are "your wifi drivers" and what wireless adapter is used?

Answer (score 0):

When you install Ubuntu depending on what wireless card you have you might have to install them by using Software & Updates. I recommend using a wired connection so your system can scan for the necessary drivers

Open up Software & Updates and choose Add additional drivers, let your system search for the appropriate drivers for your system

If there are any drivers available you will be giving a list to choose from just pick from the list and apply the changes after that you should be able to see any and all available wireless

A Lenovo Ideapad might be a little different but I'm sure it connects to a wireless connection the same way other machines do

I found this post it's  not the same model but it might still help

This post may also help you with this issue
[Ubuntu 14.04 in lenovo g700 can't detect any wireless networks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486308/ubuntu-14-04-in-lenovo-g700-cant-detect-any-wireless-networks)