# BCM43142 drops down, slow and ask pass

Tags: wireless, broadcom

after almost two days of goggling my wifi problem. There is no answer, so i came here for some help. So my laptop is a dell 14z with BCM43142 on Ubuntu 14.10.

The problem is that the wifi is really slow, sometimes drops down and also ask for the password.

Here some info: http://pastebin.com/4uxAaANf

Posts checked without success:

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/q/55868/62483)
[how to enable drivers for BCM43142](https://askubuntu.com/q/402341/62483)
https://askubuntu.com/a/460616/62483

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wanna downgrade the driver cause I have the same card and this:

Lenovo ThinkPad E545

Network controller : Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)

If you are using this WIFI card, beware that *bcmwf-kernel-source* does perform very badly with a newer version
of the *bcmwf-kernel-source* 6.30.223.248-bdcom-0ubuntuXX (XX I have tried them all and all are crap)

Desripction of what is happening:

You are connnected to a network and when you are at signal level cca 55% and less the internet drops and you are offline for a long period of time (restarting card works for a few moments when the drop occurs again)

Solution: You want to downgrade to a *bcmwf-kernel-source* 6.30.223.141 (Lock it and don't update it)
+ To be sure I also downgrade linux-firmware from 1.127.12 to 1.127, just to be sure

Alternative solution: I have read a lots of lenovo users have this kind of a problem and it was DUE a unstable N module in the driver, so you might wanna disable N module of the new bcmwf. Look it up how to, I am OK with just downgrade.

Anyone from LINUX MINT TEAM please include a backport version of *bcmwf-kernel-source* 6.30.223.141 to a linux mint 17.2 :)

Possible WARNINGS: *bcmwf-kernel-source* 6.30.223.141 might not be included in Linux MINT 17.2 as the newer versions are believed to be working properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I installed the 6.30.223.141 version a few months ago and now everything is running okay. In my case it was not necessary to downgrade the linux-firmware. So yes, this is the best solution for now.