# WiFi adapter not detected in LUbuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, dell

I just installed Lubuntu 14.04 on my Dell inspiron 5520. But as often happens with a new operating system, there is no wifi for me now. I can only connect to internet using the ethernet connection. I also looked at Dell's site, they dont have drivers for Ubuntu for this particular laptop.

wireless script output:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 10 Apr 2015 19:44 IST +0530
Booted last: 11 Apr 2015 00:25 IST +0530
Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Lubuntu

##### lspci #############################


07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:056a]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 017: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

'pccardctl' is not installed (package "pcmciautils").

##### rfkill ############################

5: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

dell_wmi               12761  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
dell_laptop            18168  0 
bcma                   52320  0 
dcdbas                 14928  1 dell_laptop
wmi                    19193  1 dell_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:be:d9:32:70:ff  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d6be:d9ff:fe32:70ff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:97569 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:60735 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:130859069 (130.8 MB)  TX bytes:5258823 (5.2 MB)


##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool ###########################


NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        D4:BE:D9:32:70:FF

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.2
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1



##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=D4:BE:D9:32:70:FF,

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########



##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").
##### iwlist channels ###################
eth0      no frequency information.
lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################
```

Comment: Please visit http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and [edit] your question to include the output of the wireless script.  This will help us help you! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried http://askubuntu.com/questions/402341/how-to-enable-drivers-for-bcm43142

Comment: I'm sorry for being an idiot but I didn't install the additional drivers for my adapter. Sorry to spam and waste your time.

Comment: i it working now ?

Answer (score -1):

You can reinstall network-manager and do a proper update for a first investigation. You can restart the service network-manager as well!!

/etc/init.d/network-manager restart